# What free service to use for storing event statistic?

Tags: android, google-sheets, flurry, parse-platform

Now to **analyze** what `Activities` users are opening in my app and other analytic data I am using **events** from [flurry](http://www.flurry.com/). But it's not possible to download all events with custom data for each event on the PC. I want to download it in xml (or txt or csv) to analyse it in Excel as an example.

- [parse.com](http://www.parse.com) - now I am going to use it. But 1 000 000 queries/month is free so if app have more than 100 000 installations ... :(
- *submit form for google-spreadsheet* - good, but there are several moments.

Does anybody know other free services for events tracking from which I can download data?

**Requirements:** I must have an opportunity to get **table with 4 columns**:

- *installationId* ([smth like this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html));
- *eventDateTime* (CurrentTime for event);
- *eventName* (may be ActivityName or CustomEventName);
- *customDataForThisEvent* (custom string data for this event).

All of this data I'll set in code.

Comment: Flurry has an API for retrieving event data: http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=API/Code/EventMetrics Is there something we don't supply in the API that you want to retrieve? (disclaimer, I work at Flurry)

Comment: @spacemanaki When I am using http://api.flurry.com/eventMetrics/Event?apiAccessCode=... it gives me consolidated info for event ("total" is everywhere). How can I get event with my parameters without GROUP BY totalCount?

Comment: @spacemanaki This is something I am also interested in. I would want to be able to supply Parameters and their Keys with query, to retrieve information according to them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/)?  It doesn't create Excel spreadsheet by default but a quick google search reveals plenty of tools for generating XLS reports from analytics data.

Comment: and you can access the data from Google Analytics with the Reports API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

Comment: I've added Requirements for the received data in my question. Will GA give me an opportunity to get data as I described?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Cobub Razor](http://github.com/cobub/razor) is OK for you. It has event statistics data. 
Because it's open source, so you can get the all data from database if you want.

But you should set up your own server to collect the data.It depends on how important the data is.